# how to install all kali linux libraries?

Tags: libraries

i'm living hell just to install one tool , to install the tool i needed 3 more libraries but the problem is to install each library i need additional libraries and to each additional libraries i need additional libraries and the biggest and best of all , some libraries A needs some libraries B but when i try to install libraries B they ask for libraries A . i even downloaded the full kali linux but it doesn't change the problem , is there anyway to have a mega libraries pack ?

Comment: I don't think you really understand what's going on here... You don't install "all kali linux libraries"... there are tens, maybe even hundreds, of thousands of libraries. How and what are you installing and if it is missing it's dependencies, what have you done to try to install them? If you are using the embedded package manager it should prompt to do install it for you, if you are using apt-get, then after the package with unsatisfied dependencies are you doing "sudo apt-get install -f" to fix the missing dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a "mega libraries pack". What we have is a *fundamental* misunderstanding of how packages work.

Your package manager should handle any dependencies of packaged software. If circular dependancies happen, something is *clearly* wrong, and you should probably switch to a saner distribution

If you are compiling, the documentation should suggest a *minimal* version of the libraries you need, and you can often start there.

That said, you could probably build a list of prerequisites with apt-get build-dep and start from there to work out what you need.

Comment: i'm sorry sir but i'm quite  a noob right now , you say to change distribution but i'm using kali linux , i think that kali is reliable enough to be used , there must be a solution to this circular dependancies thing , should i uninstall it and re install everything again ? because i also have some other issues for exemple when i launch wireshark i have a segmentation fault error

Comment: If you're a noob, its all the more reason not to run kali and stick to a main stream, well supported distro.